# Using generic TItem with "onchange" events in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a generic selector component in Blazor WebAssembly that invokes a function based on an `onchange` event when an option is selected. The problem is that the `ChangeEventArgs` is of type object and I'm not able to cast it to `TItem` without getting the error `Specified cast is not valid`. Is there a way around this? How do I get events to work properly in a generic component like this?

```
@typeparam TItem

<select class="form-control selectpicker" value="@Selected" @onchange="Update">
    @foreach (var item in Options)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }
</select>

@code {

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Options { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public TItem Selected { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TItem> SelectedChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task Update(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await SelectedChanged.InvokeAsync((TItem) e.Value); // e.Value is type object, cast to TItem fails
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing a List of complex objects to Options, then these cannot be rendered directly to HTML and then mapped back to the source complex object after selection.

### Demo of issue

Run the following and change to Item 2 on the 2nd Selector (string) and you'll get no error.  Change to Item 2 on the 1st Select (OptionItem - complex) and you'll get the error:

**GenericSelector.razor**

```
@typeparam TItem

<select class="form-control selectpicker" value="@Selected" @onchange="Update">
    @foreach (var item in Options)
    {
        <option value="@item">@item</option>
    }
</select>

@code {

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Options { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public TItem Selected { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TItem> SelectedChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task Update(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await SelectedChanged.InvokeAsync((TItem)e.Value); 
    }
}
```

**GenericSelectorPage.razor**

```
@page "/genericselector"
@using NMW.Blazor.Components.GenericSelector

<GenericSelector TItem="OptionItem" Options=@Options />
<GenericSelector TItem="string" Options=@StringOptions />

@code {        
    List<OptionItem> Options { get; set; }
    List<string> StringOptions { get; set; }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Options = new List<OptionItem>
        {
            new OptionItem { Id = "1", Text = "One"},
            new OptionItem { Id = "2", Text = "Two"}
        };

        StringOptions = new List<string>
        {
            "One",
            "Two"
        };

        base.OnInitialized();
    }


    public class OptionItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }

}
```

### One Possible Solution

**Declare interface in your select component:**

```
public interface ISelectable
{
    string Id { get; }
    string Text { get; }
}
```

**Add a partial code-behind file, so that you can constrain the type parameter:**

```
public partial class GenericSelector<TItem> where TItem : ISelectable
{ }
```

**Implement ISelectable on your complex object:**

```
public class ComplexOptionItem : ISelectable
{
    // ISelectable Implementation
    public string Id => MyId;
    public string Text => MyText;

    // Original Properties
    public string MyId { get; set; }
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

If you do not want to change your original complex object to implement ISelectable then **declare a ComplexOptionView class that inherits from ComplexOptionItem and implements ISelectable**

```
public class ComplexOptionView : ComplexOptionItem, ISelectable
{
    // ISelectable Implementation
    public string Id => MyId;
    public string Text => MyText;
}
```

**Update your generic selector component to use ISelectable** to get the display properties for rendering and then retrieve the complex object from the passed in parameter:

```
@typeparam TItem

<select class="form-control selectpicker" value="@Selected" @onchange="Update">
    @foreach (ISelectable item in Options)
    {
        <option value="@item.Id">@item.Text</option>
    }
</select>

@code {

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Options { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public TItem Selected { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<TItem> SelectedChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task Update(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Retrieve original option based on Id
        TItem selected = Options.Single(i => i.Id == e.Value);
        // Raise the SelectedChanged event using the source object
        await SelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(selected);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a great answer. Your example made me realise what the actual problem was in my case. The generic type that I was testing with was of type `int`, while the return event ( `e.Value`) is of type string. Casting to the `TItem` type (in this case `int`) would not work as it's not possible to cast string to int in that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `Item` for your selector with value:

```
<MySelector Options="availableTags" SelectedChanged="(val) => { selectedTag = availableTags.Single(x => x.Id == new Guid((string)val)); }">
<Item>
    <option  value="@context.Id">@context.Name</option>
</Item>    
</MySelector>
```

Now, the value that is returned from `SelectedChanged` is type of `object` but it is actually `string`, that is convertible to `Guid` (because value is specified as `context.Id`, which is of type `Guid`).

`availableTags` is list of `Tag` type with `Name` and `Id` :

```cs
 public class Tag
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
     public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Also change your selector to accept `Item` and return `object` on change, also there is no need for `Selected` parameter:

```
@typeparam TItem

<select class="form-control selectpicker"  @onchange="Update" >
    @foreach (var item in Options)
    {
        @Item(item)
    }
</select>

@code {

    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Options { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public EventCallback<object> SelectedChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> Item { get; set; }

    private async Task Update(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await SelectedChanged.InvokeAsync(e.Value); 
    }
}
```